# One of the identified items was in an invalid format - Microsoft.SqlServer.Type

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geography, sqlgeography

I'm trying to retrieve geography data from my SQl Server 2012 DB with:

```
new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [SpatialColumn] FROM [SpatialTable]", myConnection).Fill(myDatatable);
```

When the data is a Sql Server 2008 geography type such as `Polygon`, it's all working fine. But when the type is the new `CurvePolygon` then that line of code crashes with the error:

```
System.FormatException occurred
Message="One of the identified items was in an invalid format."
Source="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types"
StackTrace: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeoData.Read(BinaryReader r)
```

In this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx), in the section called *SQL CLR Data Types* I have read that when you reference the SqlTypes assembly version 11.0, and version 10.0 is also installed, you may see a similar error. So I changed my Config file as explained. But it hasn't solved my issue.

Any idea greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following binding redirect:

```
 <assemblyBinding>   
      <!--....-->
     <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
```

It looks like there is a problem with the loading assembly. More here: https://blog.devart.com/adventures-of-clr-types-in-net-framework.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It worked fine in SQL-Server 2012 but not in SQL-Server 2008. I had to consume my `Geography` data, using `SqlDataReader.GetSqlBytes` and then deserialize.

`var geo = SqlGeography.Deserialize(dr.GetSqlBytes(0))`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer! Unfortunately the crash happens before I can even get a `DataReader` or fill my `DataTable`. It crashes during the `Fill`

Comment: Have you really tried using a plain vanilla reader and not an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the SQLGEOGRAPHY object try Converting the SQLType to Text in the DB.

```
new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SpatialColumn.STAsText() FROM [SpatialTable]", myConnection).Fill(myDatatable);
```

Now your data should come through in the format;

```
"POLYGON((-123.22,102.32...."
```

or

```
"CURVEPOLYGON((-123.22,102.32...."
```

As either Type can be expressed as Text which will successfully fill the column in your DataTable.