# I'm receiving an error: DataReader.GetFieldType(33) returned null

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

when trying to run my site on my server I receive the following error. Works fine locally. I have tried referencing the Microsoft.SqlServer.Type and installing the NuGet Package: Microsoft.SqlServer.Type but still recieve the error on my server.

"DataReader.GetFieldType(33) returned null."

This field is a geometry field.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding the following to my web.config file:
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One of the identified items was in an invalid format - Microsoft.SqlServer.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830955/one-of-the-identified-items-was-in-an-invalid-format-microsoft-sqlserver-type)